# Reduce function is not showing all the roots of a transcendental equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am using Mathematica 9. I have done one mathematica code to find the roots of a transcendental equation. The code is given below:

```
A = BesselJ[1, x]/BesselJ[0, x];
A1 = A*x;
nclm = 1.4271;
ncom = 1.4446;
lamda = 1.55;
a1 = 52.5;
V1 = 2*Pi*a1/lamda;
V = V1*Sqrt[ncom^2 - nclm^2];
w = Sqrt[V^2 - x^2];
B = BesselK[1, w]/BesselK[0, w];
B1 = B*w;
Plot[{A1, B1}, {x, 0, 50}]
Reduce[A1 - B1 == 0 && 0 < x < 50]
```

After simulate this code, I am getting the all outputs, but the `Reduce` function is not showing all the roots, `Reduce` function shows 13 number of roots, but the equation has 15 number of roots as seen from the intersection points of the plot.

[image]

As the equation has two more roots after `x = 39.0978`, but these two roots are not showing.

Is there any way to show that roots?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use exact numbers (see [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html))

```
A = BesselJ[1, x]/BesselJ[0, x];
A1 = A*x;
nclm = 1.4271 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
ncom = 1.4446 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
lamda = 1.55 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
a1 = 52.5 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
V1 = 2*Pi*a1/lamda;
V = V1*Sqrt[ncom^2 - nclm^2];
w = Sqrt[V^2 - x^2];
B = BesselK[1, w]/BesselK[0, w];
B1 = B*w;

roots = {Reduce[A1 - B1 == 0 && 0 < x < 50] // N // ToRules}
```

[image]

```
(*  {{x -> 2.35543}, {x -> 5.40651}, {x -> 8.47513}, {x -> 11.5471}, 
     {x -> 14.6195}, {x -> 17.6912}, {x -> 20.7614}, {x -> 23.8295}, 
     {x -> 26.8946}, {x -> 29.9557}, {x -> 33.0116}, {x -> 36.0601}, 
     {x -> 39.0978}, {x -> 42.1179}, {x -> 45.1024}}  *)

Length[roots]

(*  15  *)

Plot[{A1, B1}, {x, 0, 50},
 Epilog -> {Green, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Point[{x, A1} /. roots]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is enough to increase WorkingPrecision:

```
Reduce[A1 - B1 == 0 && 0 < x < 50, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
x == 2.35543 || x == 5.40651 || x == 8.47513 || x == 11.5471 ||  x == 14.6195 || x == 17.6912 || x == 20.7614 || x == 23.8295 ||  x == 26.8946 || x == 29.9557 || x == 33.0116 || x == 36.0601 ||  x == 39.0978 || x == 42.1179 || x == 45.1024
```

Comment: Decreasing it works, too: `Reduce[A1 - B1 == 0 && 0 < x < 50, WorkingPrecision -> 1]` gives the same output as the higher `WorkingPrecision`.